# how can i run visual studio 2013 and android studio emulator on one computer

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, android-studio

I install visual studio 2013 and android studio on my computer. Visual studio 2013 emulator is run perfectly but android studio emulator is not run and found for intel haxm installed. when i installed intel haxm it shows the following error.

1. This computer does not support intel virtualization Technology (VT-x).HAXM cannot be installed.Please refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.

Comment: oooohhh... this is real problem.... your CPU not support VT-X so is going be a problem to run QEMU (android emulator)... https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KVM

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not because you have installed both **Android Studio** and **VS**. It's because you want to use HAXM which requires intel virtualization support & your computer do not support virtualization.

If you want to use Emulator for **Android Studio**, you can try GenyMotion. It's fast and do not requires virtualization support. Download Link is Here https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download

**[EDIT]**

One more thing i want to add is Virtualization is not compulsory for emulator to work on **Android Studio**. But if virtualization is there then it will be good , It can increase your emulator's speed multiple times. I am not a **VS** user , So I can't comment on **VS** 's emulator.

Comment: But how VS Emulator run with out virtualization support on my computer?

Comment: But you said " Visual studio 2013 emulator is run perfectly " in your question itself . you said only problem is Android Studio's emulator

Comment: I found that my pc model support virtualization so i reduce my problem simply by off the hyper-v windows feature that is recommended to turn on in VS.